# Gson parsing path element throw an exception

Tags: php, android, json, gson

i'm facing a problem during a parse of a JSON string in my android application.
I'm trying to receive some data from my database located on my website. The php script which execute this request encode the data queried in database in a JSON string. An example of this string is :

```
{"file0":["name":"intro.wmv","path":"C:\\Temp","bla":"0"],"file1":["name":"video.‌​avi","path":"C:\\Temp","bla":"0"]}
```

This file is an array of elements of type FILE which has some properties like the "filename", "folder path".
Once i receive this string in my android application, when i try to parse it using GSON :

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<MyFiles>>() {}.getType();
List<MyFiles> yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(sResponse, listType);
```

it throws an exception. Something wrong happens with the "folder path" property, because if i remove it from the JSON string, all goes well!
Probably the issue is due to the backslash char '\' ...

Someone faced this issue before?? Have you any hint to resolve this problem ???

Thanks in advance 
Paolo

Comment: Have you tried to escape backslashes? Thmt like this "C:\\\\Temp"

Comment: Actually they are already escaped... the string in the database is C:\Temp

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how `["intro.wmv","C:\\Temp","0"]` could match `MyFile` object. You should specify the field names rather than values in a array.
For example `{"fileName":"intro.wmv","path","C:\\Temp","size":"0"}`

Comment: Sorry....my fault. Actually the JSON string received is as you suggested: {"file0":["name":"intro.wmv","path":"C:\\Temp","bla":"0"],"file1":["name":"video.avi","path":"C:\\Temp","bla":"0"]}

Comment: not correct, it should be `[{"name":"intro.wmv","path":"C:\\Temp","bla":"0"},{"name":"video.‌​avi","path":"C:\\Temp","bla":"0"}]`